# MongoDb C# query performance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the `MongoDB C# Driver` 2.14.1 and a `Mongo Server v3.6` running on a Docker container. I'm running an easy (I think) query over 3 collections. The biggest collection has 400k documents, each document averaged 64Kb. I'm filtering by two fields and returning the results in a cursor to reduce overhead. The results are sorted by descending by a field that is configured as an index as well. This is happening on my production server which is taking nearly `1GB of memory` (not being released afterwards). The following queries explained (run on the server):

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "table1",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "Type" : {
                                                "$eq" : "Type1"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "LocationId" : {
                                                "$eq" : "Location1"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "Date" : {
                                                "$gt" : ISODate("2021-01-18T23:00:00Z")
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                        {
                                                "Type" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "Type1"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "LocationId" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "Location1"
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "Date" : -1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "Date_-1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "Date" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : true,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "Date" : [
                                                "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1611010800000))"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 2,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 7,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 7,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                        {
                                                "Type" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "Type1"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "LocationId" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "Location1"
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 1,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 8,
                        "advanced" : 1,
                        "needTime" : 6,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 7,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 7,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 8,
                                "advanced" : 7,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 0,
                                "restoreState" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "Date" : -1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "Date_-1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "Date" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : true,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "Date" : [
                                                "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1611010800000))"
                                        ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 7,
                                "seeks" : 1,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "7aa23bd7fe20",
                "port" : 27018,
                "version" : "3.6.18",
                "gitVersion" : "2005f25eed7ed88fa698d9b800fe536bb0410ba4"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

The second query:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "table2",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "Type" : {
                                                "$eq" : "Type1"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "LocationId" : {
                                                "$eq" : "02"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "Date" : {
                                                "$gt" : ISODate("2021-01-18T23:00:00Z")
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                        {
                                                "Type" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "Type1"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "LocationId" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "02"
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "Date" : -1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "Date_-1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "Date" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : true,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "Date" : [
                                                "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1611010800000))"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 63,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 9896,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 9896,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                        {
                                                "Type" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "Type1"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "LocationId" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "02"
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 1,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 50,
                        "works" : 9897,
                        "advanced" : 1,
                        "needTime" : 9895,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 77,
                        "restoreState" : 77,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 9896,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 9896,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 9897,
                                "advanced" : 9896,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 77,
                                "restoreState" : 77,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "Date" : -1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "Date_-1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "Date" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : true,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "Date" : [
                                                "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1611010800000))"
                                        ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 9896,
                                "seeks" : 1,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "7aa23bd7fe20",
                "port" : 27018,
                "version" : "3.6.18",
                "gitVersion" : "2005f25eed7ed88fa698d9b800fe536bb0410ba4"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

And the third:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "table3",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "Type" : {
                                                "$eq" : "Type1"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "LocationId" : {
                                                "$eq" : "52"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "Date" : {
                                                "$gt" : ISODate("2021-01-18T23:00:00Z")
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                        {
                                                "Type" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "Type1"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "LocationId" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "52"
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "Date" : -1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "Date_-1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "Date" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : true,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "Date" : [
                                                "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1611010800000))"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 30,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 934,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 366370,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 366370,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                        {
                                                "Type" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "Type1"
                                                }
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "LocationId" : {
                                                        "$eq" : "52"
                                                }
                                        }
                                ]
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 30,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 889,
                        "works" : 366371,
                        "advanced" : 30,
                        "needTime" : 366340,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 2862,
                        "restoreState" : 2862,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "docsExamined" : 366370,
                        "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 366370,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 160,
                                "works" : 366371,
                                "advanced" : 366370,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 2862,
                                "restoreState" : 2862,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "Date" : -1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "Date_-1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "Date" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : true,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "Date" : [
                                                "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1611010800000))"
                                        ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 366370,
                                "seeks" : 1,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "7aa23bd7fe20",
                "port" : 27018,
                "version" : "3.6.18",
                "gitVersion" : "2005f25eed7ed88fa698d9b800fe536bb0410ba4"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Now with my little knowledge of the "explainPlan" I would have imagined that the performance is OK, and not many records get returned on each query. Having said that I can see a pattern when I run the code via the .NET application (C# code) that makes the CPU go through the roof and right after the memory follows in the Mongo server Docker container.

I don't know if there is misconfigured or whether I can do something to improve the performance of it because I'm quite puzzle with the performance on just that query - I think is this query because the rest of the queries with similar amount of data on different parts of the system work quite well. Besides that, is there any mechanism or tool I can use to diagnose the memory consumption in my `Mongo` server?

Comment: I would recommend trying not so ancient driver version first :)

Comment: My mistake, it is 2.14.1